# When is the best time to switch gears in OutRun?

Tags: outrun

When is the best time to switch from low gear to high gear in the original OutRun (1986)? Should I switch gears as soon as the speed bar turns green, or is it better to wait until I reach a specific speed?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this guide on GameFaqs](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/arcade/564002-outrun/faqs/80160/common-strategies)

> Switching from low to high gear while the accelerometer is in the
> "green" is your ideal sweet spot. It always makes the gear switch
> smooth and effortless, and doesn't detract you from speed the way it
> would if it were in the "blue" or "red".

Although see further down for details of a quick start exploit that requires you to start in high gear.

Comment: Is it faster to switch as soon as it turns green, or is it the same speed if you switch later as long as it's still green?